# youtube stops when i close ipad case

Tags: ipad

I stream youtube meditation video on bluetooth earbuds while going to sleep. I close the case and it stops so I open it and restart. runs all night!!! until a few days ago. now when I reopen the case and restart it goes back to home screen and shuts off the stream.
I have not updated recently. I have made no changes nor have I done anything different.How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use an app called Musi it works on my iPhone anyways.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube prevents you from listening to music in the background unless you pay for [YouTube Red](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/youtube-red-details/).

You can circumvent this issue by using YouTube in Safari at [youtube.com](https://youtube.com) instead of in the YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try changing your auto lock/unlock settings especially if you have a smart cover:

Go to Settings -> General-> iPad Cover Lock / Unlock option.

Sound like you want it turned off :)